# How to run nested batch file programatically using C#

Tags: c#, batch-file, process

I am trying to execute a batch  through my Client/server socket program. Inside the main batch file, it calls other batch files . All batch files exist in the same folder. The Server program application is in exist another folder (E:\Apps)  and running it as windows  service.

Main batch file Path :

> E:\MyApp\UAT\guest\mytasks\Main.bat

Inside the main batch file below calls are made

> call E:\MyApp\UAT\guest\mytasks\stop.bat
>
> call %mytasks%\start.bat

When I execute the Main.bat file, my program returns the below error and not the executing  rest of the code in the Main.bat file.

> '.\stop.bat' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Function call

> ExecuteShellCommand(": E:\MyApp\UAT\guest\mytasks\Main.bat", "E:\", ref Output, ref Error);

```
private static void ExecuteShellCommand(string _FileToExecute, string _CommandLine, ref string _outputMessage, ref string _errorMessage)
{

// Set process variable
// Provides access to local and remote processes and enables you to start and stop local system processes.
System.Diagnostics.Process eodProcess = null;
try
{
    eodProcess = new System.Diagnostics.Process();

    // invokes the cmd process specifying the command to be executed.
    string _CMDProcess = string.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, @"{0}\cmd.exe", new object[] { Environment.SystemDirectory });

    // pass executing file to cmd (Windows command interpreter) as a arguments
    // /C tells cmd that we want it to execute the command that follows, and then exit.
    string _Arguments = string.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "/C {0}", new object[] { _FileToExecute });

    // pass any command line parameters for execution
    if (_CommandLine != null && _CommandLine.Length > 0)
    {
        _Arguments += string.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, " {0}", new object[] { _CommandLine, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture });
    }

    // Specifies a set of values used when starting a process.
    System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo eodProcessStartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(_CMDProcess, _Arguments);
    // sets a value indicating not to start the process in a new window. 
    eodProcessStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    // sets a value indicating not to use the operating system shell to start the process. 
    eodProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    // sets a value that indicates the output/input/error of an application is written to the Process.
    eodProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    eodProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    eodProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    eodProcess.StartInfo = eodProcessStartInfo;

    // Starts a process resource and associates it with a Process component.
    eodProcess.Start();

    // Instructs the Process component to wait indefinitely for the associated process to exit.
    _errorMessage = eodProcess.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
    eodProcess.WaitForExit();


    // Instructs the Process component to wait indefinitely for the associated process to exit.
    _outputMessage = eodProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    eodProcess.WaitForExit();

}

catch (Exception _Exception)
{
    // Error
    Console.WriteLine("Exception caught in process: {0}", _Exception.ToString());
}
finally
{
    // close process and do cleanup
    eodProcess.Close();
    eodProcess.Dispose();
    eodProcess = null;
}
```

}

Comment: Do you get the same error if you move the main.bat to another directory and leave the stop.bat where it is?

Comment: @FlorianDohrendorf, I tried but it giving the same error message

Comment: I tried to reproduce your error but unfortunately i wasn't able to. Is the colon and space in your `ExecuteShellCommand` what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`'.\stop.bat' is not recognized as an internal or external command,` means that stop.bat isn't being found in your current active directory, or the directory the original batch file was executed in. However, this may not be the case because the actual process that executed the batch file was in C# program, and may not be in the same directory as the stop.bat file. Try putting it into the same directory as the C# program.